# set image view hovered on click in android

Tags: android, imageview

i have an image view that i use like a button, and when i click it  start an action,now i would like to change the background of the imageView on click as if it were a normal button.

for example:

```
 image view not hovered -> BackgroundImageViewNotHovered

 image view hovered -> BackgroundImageViewHovered
 ...
```

my xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonImage" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i have implemented a listener like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foo_fragment, container, false);
        button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Action());
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are talking about the image src here is a solution. Please try it and let me know

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.login);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  button.setImageResource(R.drawable.<The image that you want>);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we talking about background property of ImageView you can use the next code:

```
ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);

imageButton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_background_image);
  }
}
```

**UPD 1**.
If you want to use a drawable XML with button states (selector) (**buttonImage.xml** as I understood), you should also use string:

```
imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_background_image);
```

instead of:

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_background_image);
```

or (it's the same) in your XML

```
android:src="@drawable/buttonImage"
```